# How can I package Excel and Python together and distribute to business users?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to automate a data processing task for one of my customer.
We receive raw data in Excel. The task is to process these data sets and generate the required output to respective other tabs in the same Excel file. The entire data processing code will be in Python 3. The customer wants to distribute the program to different other business users, so that they can generate the output by them-self on click of a button in Excel.

The business user will not have Python installed in their system.

I know this can be achieved easily in VBA macro, but customer’s requirement is Python. It would be great if someone answers the steps

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The dude auditing my initial answer didn't believe in it because it was just a link.

So here I've copied the instructions from that project and used the link as supplementary. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZSZHmWSOeM

### **Py to exe Project**

**Prerequisites**

Python : Python 2.7 or Python 3.3+ (basically anything that pyinstaller runs on)

Chrome : to run the user interface

**Installing**

Download the zipped folder

Open cmd/terminal and `cd` to the unzipped folder (recommend putting it on your desktop for now)

Execute `pip install -r requirements.txt`

**Running the Application**

Run `run.py`. Chrome will open in app mode with the project running inside.

**Using the Application**

Select your script location (paste in or use the file explorer)

Address-box outline will become blue when file exists

Select other options and add things like an icon or other files

Click the big blue button at the bottom to convert

Find your converted files in /output when completed

**Passing the File With Arguments**

Alternatively you can execute python `run.py [filename]`. This will open up the window with the filename in the script location.